# How do I access a range of cells that are not adjacent? (LibreOffice Calc / Microsoft Excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

I am trying to compute the average of some data points. I need to compute the average of cells C49, C271, C493, +.... C(49+222*n) but cannot figure out how to do this using a formula in my spreadsheet because I can't access a cell with a variable as the row. I have to add up 260 values, which would make it very tedious and annoying to calculate out individually

Comment: the reason I cannot arrange my data in a different wayis because my spreadsheet is ~600,000 lines long

Answer (score 3):

Use INDEX()

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INDEX(C:C,(ROW($1:$260)-1)*222+49))/260
```

With Office 365 we can use SEQUENCE:

```
=SUM((INDEX(C:C,SEQUENCE(260*222,,49,222))/260
```

Comment: thank you so much. I am a beginner to spreadsheet calculations